# How to solve Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::destroy() in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, get, routes, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $user->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->username !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->phone !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $user->address !!}</td>
        <td>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
            <div class='btn-group'>
                <a href="{!! route('users.edit', [$user->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

My routes\web.php is like this :

```
Route::get('users/destroy/{year}', 'UserController@destroy')->name('users.destroy.year');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function destroy($id, $year)
{
    $user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($user)) {
        Flash::error('User not found');

        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }

    $this->userRepository->delete($id);

    Flash::success('User deleted successfully.');

    // return redirect(route('users.index'));
    return redirect(route('users.index.year', ['year' => $year]));
}
```

There is exist error like this :

```
ErrorException in UserController.php line 205: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::destroy()
```

And the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/10`

When click button delete, I want the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2020`

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: You need to supply the year as well in `'route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id]`, you're currently missing one argument.

Comment: @Joel Hinz, I change like this : `{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id, $year], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}`. When I click button delete, the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/10?2020`. So, it's not working

Comment: Looks like you're also missing the user id from the route definition.

Comment: @Joel Hinz,I using http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/ or https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3. seems the delete have been generated automatically. so no need to add routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$year = 2020;
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id, $year], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
```

Comment: I change like this : `{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id, $year], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}`. When I click button delete, the url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/10?2020`. So, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :
In routes/web.php just declare the route resource

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

In you form add an input hidden with the year value

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}


<input type="hidden" name="year" value="2020">
```

And update your controller like that

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
$user = $this->userRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
$year = $request->year;
if (empty($user)) {
    Flash::error('User not found');

    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}

$this->userRepository->delete($id);

Flash::success('User deleted successfully.');

// return redirect(route('users.index'));
return redirect('users/index/'.$year);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong route name in your `open` method, it should be `users.destroy.year`.

So your form will look as:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy.year', $user->id, $year], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
```

Comment: I had change it. But, there is exist error like this : `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:` and in url looks like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/destroy/2?2016`

Comment: Change your route to use `delete` verb as `Route::delete(...)`. Try it, if it solves your problem.

Comment: I using http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/ or https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3. Seems the delete have been generated automatically. So no need to add routes.

Comment: Seems I need your help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788737/why-the-deleted-data-still-appear-in-the-interface